# How to pin an image/view inside a UIScrollView when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview

I've been searching for a way to pin views/images to the top of a UIScrollView when scrolling. However the posts/articles I came across are not in swift 3. I'm not sure if I'm typing my question in the web correctly. So my question is how can we achieve the same behavior as a UITableView or UICollectionView. When you scroll, a section will stick to the top until another section pushes it up. I'm wondering would we be able to use views/image and pin them at the top of the UIScrollView. Down below is a screenshot of a UIScrollView that has 4 views.

[image]

So when scrolling I would like to pin the first view/image to the top until another view/image pushes it. Also would it be possible to determine which view sticks to the top. So lets say I only want the red views to stick until another red view pushes it. Been looking for a way to achieve this type of behavior for a while now.

Please help, would really appreciate any help provided at this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to do this, but you can use the `scrollView` `delegate`’s `scrollViewDidScroll` to capture the `contentOffset` and use a combination of the target view’s `origin/center/transform` properties to keep the view where you want it.

There’s a neat video explaining how to do this that Apple released during WWDC 2010, called something like “Advanced Scroll View Behavior”, if I remember correctly. It’s definitely worth a watch.